# The basics of using Visual Studio Code - debugging and compiling

Tags: c#, mono, visual-studio-code

**Background**

I have programmed in VB .NET for many years now but am trying to learn a language that is more "cross platform" compatible as well as broaden my language knowledge of learning C#. I did my own research and determined that I want to learn C# and try using Visual Studio Code as my editor to do so.

*-I have looked through the many examples and questions that both this site as well as others have but they all seem to not really show too much about setting up tasks or a compiler.-*

**What I am trying to do**

So far all I am trying to do are basic examples like "Hello world" and very simple *console applications* for the time being. The actual writing of the "Hello world" example is pretty straightforward to me but I am having more of a problem with learning Visual Studio Code. So here are my problems and what I have tried with each so far:

1. I wish to use Mono as my compiler. I can make a .cs file within Visual Studio Code and then from a command prompt compile the file using Mono; however, there has to be a more integrated way to do so entirely within Visual Studio Code. I can have Mono be my debugger but that of course is not the same thing as a compiler.
2. I am having a difficult time with the debugger as well. I can add mono as a debugger but then I need to choose a task. I am not very familiar with creating tasks but there seems to be templates that Visual Studio Code has so if I select one, then I have to add configurations.

I start with clicking debug, and then select Debug Console Application:

[image]

It asks me to chose an environment so I choose C# Mono:

[image]

Then a dialog appears to Add a configuration:

[image]

My application is not Java, so all of the Node.js ones do not apply, I do not want it to rely on the .NET Framework, so I am not really sure which one to pick. Even if I do pick either ".NET Attach to local .NET Core Application" which seems to fit my goal the best aside from the .NET part of it, the launch .json changes to the following:

```
{
// Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
// Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
// For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [

    {
        "name": ".NET Core Attach",
        "type": "coreclr",
        "request": "attach",
        "processId": "${command:pickProcess}"
    },
    {
        "name": "Launch",
        "type": "mono",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${workspaceRoot}/program.exe",
        "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}"
    },
    {
        "name": "Attach",
        "type": "mono",
        "request": "attach",
        "address": "localhost",
        "port": 55555
    }
]
```

}

From here when I try to debug, it states it can't find program.exe. I know that it is because of the line

```
"program": "${workspaceRoot}/program.exe",
```

But what should I have here instead?

Comment: I'd recommend using VS Community Edition instead. Might save you some headaches.

Comment: Oh, and if you want to use Mono, you might also consider using MonoDevelop. I am not up-to-date how good the integration into VS is currently.

Comment: @Fildor So MonoDevelop is basically the same thing as Xamarin now right? Is Xamarin pretty good at being cross platform as well? Does it work on linux, apple, and Windows? (of course depending on which dependencies you write a program with).

Comment: If Xamarin is not cross platform, then nothing is.

Comment: @Fildor ha fair enough. I will try with Xamarin then. Thanks for your advice!